# Add X number of product get Y number of product free

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I tried many variants but could not find the correct combination in shopping cart rules.

Here is the condition:

- In category `pins` I have some products where all have the same price.

What I want is when some one buy:

- Any 4 products 2 products free
- Any 8 products 4 products free
- Any 12 products 6 products free

So basically we want to give away 2 pins for free for every 4 pins purchased.

Magento allows to buy X product and get Y product free for same cart item quantity only.

What if we have different products in cart of same category?

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: its magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create such a rule in a sufficient way with Magento's default `Shopping Cart Price Rules`. The closest you could get is something like "Buy 4 times *the same specific product*, get two times *this same specific product* for free".

As there is no information about any custom module given neither I'll take it into consideration. So, a solution to your problem can be to purchase an extension such as https://amasty.com/special-promotions.html

With this extension you can

> **Create promotions like 'each second (third, fourth, etc) camera, phone, etc for 30% or 40% off or for free'**
>
> This Magento on sale extension adds 'Each Nth with Discount' rule, which you can utilize to offer deals like 'Get each 5th product for free (or with discount)', 'Buy 3 products from a certain category and get one of them with 40%/50% discount (or for free)' - offer a kind of tier pricing based on category or some other attributes (e.g. attribute set, manufacturer, etc).